# Create a stacked bar chart grouped by multiple x parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am experiencing difficulties creating a stacked bar chart where there are multiple grouping to the x axis.

```
 df <- data.frame(random = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                  value = c("s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s3"),
                  countries = factor(c("US", "Japan", "UK", "Germany", "France", "France", "France")),
                  week = factor(c("week1", "week2", "week1", "week2", "week1", "week1", "week2")))
```

In this example, I am trying to group the x-axis by *week* and *countries*.
I want to display the percentage of the number occurrences of *value* by grouping by *week*, *countries* and *value*. I want the output of the bars to be presented as:

- US, week1: 100%
- Japan, week2: 100%
- UK, week1: 100%
- Germany, week1: 100%
- France, week1: 50% (value-s1), 50% (value-s2)
- France, week2: 100% (value-s3)

My current code is:

```
  result <- df %>% group_by_(df$countries, df$week, df$value) %>% summarise(total = n()) #get number of occurences
  ggplot(result, aes(x = interaction(result[["countries"]], result[["week"]]), y = result[["total"]], fill = result[["total"]])) +
    geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

Are you able to help me with this logic? I believe scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) should calculate the percentage for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what filling variable should be.

```
result <- df %>% 
  unite("group", countries:week, sep = ", ") %>%
  count(group, value) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(p = round(n / sum(n), 2))

ggplot(result, aes(x = group, y = p, fill = as.factor(value))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If I understood you correctly, try:

```
result <- df %>% 
  unite("group", countries:week, sep = ", ") %>%
  count(group, value) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(p = round(n / sum(n), 2)) %>%
  separate("group", c("country", "week"), sep = ", ")

ggplot(result, aes(x = week, y = p, fill = as.factor(value))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(~country,scales = "free_x") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks for this! Really appreciate the help. This is what I expected. I was wondering, is it possible to get week2+week1 of France next to each other? i.e. the countries and all its associated weeks as a section

Comment: @coder123 if this has answered your question (which I believe it did), please consider accepting it. If you have a follow up question please consider asking it as a follow up question. This way, it will be much better visible for future readers.